# How can I validate that a date is available before prompting the user to complete the rest of a webform?

Tags: 7, webforms, forms, bookings

I have a webform that contains a date field. I need to run some code that checks to make sure the date is not already in use (i.e. that no one else has submitted a webform with that particular date). I already have the webform validation module installed, and I know I could use that (create a custom module with custom validators), but the validations don't run until the form is submitted. Because there's a required file upload, I'd rather be able to allow the user to check if the date is available before doing the upload.

Is this possible? How would I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use AJAX to check if the date is available.

In your form add a button to check for the date, for example:

```
  $form['submit-check'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => '('Check date'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'mymodule_check_date_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'datecheck-result-wrp',
    ),
  );
```

When user clicks on the button, an AJAX call is made. inside the AJAX callback you can check the date availability and return the result in the callback fucntion (mymodule_check_date_callback() in the above example).

AJAX forms are beyond a simple answer, you'll have to check the documentation. I recoomend the [Drupal 7 AJAX Forms documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/752056), the [Example for Developers  module](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) that includes AJAX form examples and the [Form API Internal Workflow Illustration](https://www.drupal.org/node/165104)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at doing it through the [Clientside Validation](http://drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) module, which also works with Webform/Webform validation.  Since this module's validation is client-side, you can give feedback sooner rather than later.  Please note that I don't know off the top of my head whether it supports out-of-the-box the specific date-checking functionality you are looking for.

Comment: I looked at that, but the issue isn't that date is a complex field type, it's that I need to do a database query to get the value to validate against. I don't know that this module supports that any more than the webform validation one does.

Comment: In that case, what about just making a separate little widget to check the date first?  Then, if it validates, it redirects to the webform and prefills the value; if not, it prompts you to input another day.

Comment: That sounds like it would do what I need. I'm pretty new to Drupal - how would I do that?

Comment: That would require writing some custom code which is beyond what I can provide here as part of my answer.  Perhaps someone else knows how to get what you want using one of the contributed modules.

Comment: I'm not asking you to write the code, but what would be the basic setup? A custom module that displays a form in a block?

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach might be to use the [Availability Calendars](https://www.drupal.org/project/availability_calendars) module, and then take advantage of the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) integration of this module (from its project page):

> Kick off booking process for customers (booking formlet sub-module):
>
> - Select start and end date in the calendar itself and click "book now".
> - Prefilled start and end date based on e.g. an earlier availability search.
> - Integrates with webform for further booking details.